# How to replace a react component with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

basically im rendering this react component:

```
  <Grid>
    <Him className="him"><Link to="/him">Him</Link></Him>
    <Her className="her"><Link to="/her">Her</Link></Her>
  </Grid>
```

essentially just 2 boxes with links to him and her.

I have this route that correctly renders my Categories when you click on him.

```
<Route
        path="/him"
        render={() => (
          <Categories
            products={products}
            addToBasket={addToBasket}
          />
        )}
      />
```

However it renders this component underneath the him/her components. It might sound silly but how do I get it to render them over the top or instead of it?

I could something where I set the state of the component to visible: false and toggle that but that seems a bit messy.

all the stuff in this tutorial: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match, seems to have them routing via header that never disappears, whereas I want to click on links in the body of my application and then show different content. any ideas?

Comment: You wants to render links and content of link ta the same time ? It is not enought celar to me.

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez as soon as I click on links I want to render new content and those links to disappear. does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap the Grid in a Route as well. You could do something like this

```
<Route path='/' exact component={LinkComponent} />
```

And somewhere else in your code:

```
const LinkComponent = () => (
  <Grid>
    <Him className="him"><Link to="/him">Him</Link></Him>
    <Her className="her"><Link to="/her">Her</Link></Her>
  </Grid>
);
```

This way, if you go to the home route, you see the `Grid`, and when you click on a Link, you go to corresponding route and the `Grid` will be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Ok you just wants to replace the entire content when click on `/him` or `/her`, so as  Xander Berkein said you should render your links into a main component and then assign it to the `/` main route, y that way you need to use `exact` prop to just render that first path that matches to the URL, so

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path={‘/‘} component={<Links/>} />
<Route exact path={‘/him’} component={<HimComponent/> />
<Route exact path={‘/her’} component={<HerComponent /> />
</Switch>
```

I hope you find it useful.